# Loops with Latex?

Tags: macros, texmaker, loops

I'm something new in latex and I want to add some pdf pages in my document.

For do that I slit de original pdf, because I have some problems with the format, and to insert one page I use a newcomman which I myself make:

```
\newcommand{\ipdfpag}[4]{%#1 Where is the pdf. #2 page to insert. #3 scale and #4 hspace.

  \begin{figure}[H]

  \hspace{#4}

  \includegraphics[scale=#3]{#1/#2_#1}

  \end{figure}

}
```

I don't know if this is de best way to do this, but I obtain what I want.

Okay, now I have to insert more than one pdf page, if it there are less than 4 or 5 there aren't problem, but I have more than 30, and it's very boring write something like:

```
\ipdfpag{mitos}{1}{1}{-2cm}
\newpage

\ipdfpag{mitos}{2}{1}{-2cm}
\newpage

\ipdfpag{mitos}{3}{1}{-2cm}
\newpage

\ipdfpag{mitos}{4}{1}{-2cm}
\newpage

\ipdfpag{mitos}{5}{1}{-2cm}
\newpage

[...]
```

My question is: Are there the possibility tho create a new command or other thing with the next idea:?

```
for i = 1,5

  \ipdfpag{mitos}{i}{-2cm}

end
```

I could see that there are commands like \repeat, \loop... but I couldn't understand them and I prefer more easy command.

Thanks, and sorry for my english, I'm not very good at it.